# Dynamic Controller Plugin for grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'am new to grails, I wanted to make use of Dynamic Controller Plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/dynamic-controller) in my project.

I am using grails version 3.2.11
I've added the dependency as directed on the page. It downloads the dependency in the form of zip, I can see it in External libraries. But when I am trying to import two classes (as directed on http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1041 Linking to existing Controller Actions

approach)

```
import com.burtbeckwith.grails.plugins.dynamiccontroller.ControllerClosureSource
import com.burtbeckwith.grails.plugins.dynamiccontroller.DynamicControllerManager
```

it gives " unable to resolve class" error. Please suggest what am I doing wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install a Grails 2 plugin in a Grails 3+ app, but that's not possible since they're not compatible. Grails 2 plugins must be upgraded and reworked to be used in Grails 3, and there's no plan to do so for this plugin.

Comment: Any other ways to add actions dynamically to controllers at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I would say take a look at the `URL Mappings` & `Embedded variables` in the grails documentation.
https://docs.grails.org/3.2.11/guide/single.html#embeddedVariables

For example:

```
static mappings = {
  "/blog/$topic"(controller: "blog")
}
```

which gives you a feeling like you are dynamically declaring actions.
And the `topic` variable is accessible through GrailsParameterMap `params` object @ controller.
With this you can construct url like:

1. www.mysite.com/blog/football
2. www.mysite.com/blog/tvshow
3. www.mysite.com/blog/etc

Edit: you can also take a look at `Dynamic Controller and Action Names` [https://docs.grails.org/3.2.11/guide/single.html#_dynamic_controller_and_action_names]